# The type or namespace name could not be found - C#

Tags: c#

I try to navigate internet explorer using this

```
    SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
    IE.Visible = false;
    IE.Navigate("www.testsite.com");
```

However, I get this error;

[image]

How can I fix that issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add reference 'SHDocVw' in C# project using Visual C# 2010 Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845140/add-reference-shdocvw-in-c-sharp-project-using-visual-c-sharp-2010-express)

Comment: Please post the error message instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you didn't add the right reference in order to use `SHDocVw`.

Try to add `Microsoft Internet Controls` reference (in the COM tab), and then you can include `SHDOcVw` in your class.