# What reference I should add to be able to access a particular class?

Tags: vb.net, reference

I have this code in vb.net

```
dim WebBrowser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
```

Obviously this code requires some library. Which one?

The code uses to work. I remove all references, and I forget which one I should add.

This page shows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx that it should be microsoft.internetcontrol

However, I cannot find microsoft.internetcontrol among list of references.

[image]

Comment: @soroush read the tags before you add them `Microsoft` clearly says DO NOT USE THIS TAG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845140/add-reference-shdocvw-in-c-sharp-project-using-visual-c-sharp-2010-express), you need to add the `Microsoft Internet Controls` COM object (not .NET assembly) for it to work.

In Visual Studio 2015: [image]

Comment: Before I select this as answer. Is there any general way or do we have to look up the web everytime? Why com object? Why not .net assembly?

Comment: I've always just used an educated guess, but a good rule of thumb is that .NET Assemblies have a very well defined Namespace structure (Microsoft.Windows.blahblahblah or System.Data.blahblahblah) whereas COM objects have gibberish names (SHDocVw). When its a .NET assembly, you can usually find it in the .NET list via the Namespace prefix, but when its a COM object, I have to look it up online unless I know for a fact which one it is (i think it used to show you the short name as well in some previous versions of VS).

Comment: Very well. Here's your 50. I have no uses of reputation besides this :)